# VBA form mailto hyperlink ouput to client question

Tags: email, vba, hyperlink, mailto

I have a form looking up email addresses in an excel sheet, which works fine in creating mailto hyperlinks. they look like this...

[image]

But I would like to show the person's actual name, like this, and I have the string available...

[image]

My question is whether this can be done in the way the link is constructed, or is this something the email client is doing by matching from the address book?
I would prefer to train the address book, rather than create email only addresses.

**additionally** here is a sample of what I have

```
Link = "mailto:" & EmpForm.Label10
whoTo = EmpForm.TextBox3 'which I want to use in the TO:whoever
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Link, NewWindow:=True
```

Comment: is this Excel or Outlook vba ? could you show us your code ? you could probably set the recipient field with the name you want with a few lines of code (using `split` and some character transformation) but i need to have a further look for the address book part and that would be useless if i can't understand how it is called

Comment: @JMax  Excel vba. I am expecting the default client to generally handle this, if possible, but most of these users do have outlook2003. am adding a sample of the code called on the userForm.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of following the link from Excel, meaningly, remove this part:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Link, NewWindow:=True
```

You could create a mail from Excel. Thus, you could set the parameters you want.
Here is a sample of code (found [here](http://www.exceltip.com/show_tip/Applications_-_Word,_Outlook_in_VBA/Control_Outlook_from_Excel_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/464.html)):

```
' requires a reference to the Microsoft Outlook 8.0 Object Library    
Sub SendAnEmailWithOutlook()
' creates and sends a new e-mail message with Outlook
Dim OLF As Outlook.MAPIFolder, olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ToContact As Outlook.Recipient
    Set OLF = GetObject("", _
        "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olMailItem = OLF.Items.Add ' creates a new e-mail message
    With olMailItem
        .Subject = "Subject for the new e-mail message" ' message subject
        Set ToContact = .Recipients.Add("name@domain.com") ' add a recipient
        Set ToContact = .Recipients.Add("name@company.com") ' add a recipient
        ToContact.Type = olCC ' set latest recipient as CC
        Set ToContact = .Recipients.Add("name@org.net") ' add a recipient
        ToContact.Type = olBCC ' set latest recipient as BCC
        .Body = "This is the message text" & Chr(13) 
        ' the message text with a line break
        .Attachments.Add "C:\FolderName\Filename.txt", olByValue, , _
            "Attachment" ' insert attachment
'        .Attachments.Add "C:\FolderName\Filename.txt", olByReference, , _
             "Shortcut to Attachment" ' insert shortcut
'        .Attachments.Add "C:\FolderName\Filename.txt", olEmbeddedItem, , _
             "Embedded Attachment" ' embedded attachment
'        .Attachments.Add "C:\FolderName\Filename.txt", olOLE, , _
             "OLE Attachment" ' OLE attachment
        .OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True ' delivery confirmation
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True ' read confirmation
        '.Save ' saves the message for later editing
        .Send ' sends the e-mail message (puts it in the Outbox)
    End With
    Set ToContact = Nothing
    Set olMailItem = Nothing
    Set OLF = Nothing
End Sub
```

To create your recipient field, you can use:

```
arrTo = Split(whoTo,"@")
whoTo = UCase(arrTo[0]) & " " & UCase(arrTo[1]) & "<" & whoTo & ">"
```

Comment: This would be a good solution I agree, but The message composition is totally unrelated to the excel sheet this is used from at times, and I don't care to reproduce all the editing capabilities of an email client for this. This is a schedule and double-clicking a staff name brings up information related to them. But good suggestion +1

Comment: what will happen if the user does not have the outlook client installed? It may be the best approach to do as you suggest here, but in some cases they don't.

Comment: i think that Excel will raise an error when trying to create an `Outlook.Application` object. You could try to catch it and handle it if you keep this solution

Answer (score 0):

Outlook new mail window will show you name if the e-mail address you are mailing to is present in it's address book else full e-mail address is shown.

Comment: I realize that. I know that new received emails 'train' the address book with user names and their related email addresses. I was hoping to not just populate address books with plain email addresses, but the associated name.

Comment: How are you manipulating outlook address book. From the code above, I can only make out that VBA code is just following the mail-to link and opening a new mail. I dot think e-mail address is getting saved in the address book.

Comment: Outlook just does that. Any outgoing email saves as an entry, but as the email address, not a username, since none was used. I am not manipulating Outlook, I was just hoping to send the email in such a way, that Outlook, and Outlook Express, create a more usable entry for the future